# WCF - basicHttpBinding configuration (exception: Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint ...)

Tags: c#, ssl, wcf-binding, wcf-security, x509certificate2

I'm trying to make a soap client in VisualStudio. First thing I've done was generating proxy class with delivered WSDL file (using Add Service Reference option in VisualStudio). It was generated with wrong binding configuration - message security should be:
*DefaultAsymmetricSignatureAlgorithm  - "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#**rsa-sha256**"* *DefaultCanonicalizationAlgorithm - "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/**xml-exc-c14n#**"* and *DefaultDigestAlgorithm   - "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#**sha256**"*,

while it is:
*DefaultAsymmetricSignatureAlgorithm  "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#**rsa-sha1**"* *DefaultCanonicalizationAlgorithm "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/**xml-exc-c14n#**"* and *DefaultDigestAlgorithm   "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#**sha1**"*.

I changed basicHttpBinding settings in App.conf by adding:

```
<security mode="Message">
            <message algorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256" clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
</security>
```

and binding settings changed properly, I also set certificates:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//cert.p12", "Pass");
client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
```

Unfortunately I got exception:
**The service certificate is not provided for target 'http://.../service'. Specify a service certificate in ClientCredentials.**

I tried using the same certificate for ClientCertificate and ServiceCertificate (I don't know it is okey).

`client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = cert;`

But I got error: **The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode.**

Changing mode to None gives excepion **Security not found**.

I added  `<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>` in serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceCredentials/clientCertificate, and it doesn't work.

I also tried adding  `<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>` in endpointBehaviors/behavior/clientCredentials/serviceCertificate,

but I got another error:
**"Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'nameA' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim 'nameB'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity 'nameB' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy. ”**

And I'm not sure if I go right way anymore. I don't know what to do :(

In general, sending request using **SoupUI** works fine, but I can't make right configuration in my client service to send any request.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the certificate, you need to update it :

```
<identity>
     <certificate encodedValue="xxx" />
</identity>
```

It might still be pointing to the original.